# What is the Koalas equivalent of the pandas explode() function?

Tags: python, pandas, pyspark, koala, spark-koalas

I would like to explode a Koalas column containing lists of values into multiple columns. When I am trying to use df.explode() as documented [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html), I am getting the
`AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'explode'`. I know Koalas is a relatively new API, is explode() not supported yet?

Comment: I just implemented this methods for Koalas and created a PR to https://github.com/databricks/koalas/pull/1507 If this PR will be accepted, you can use `DataFrame.explode` in Koalas directly.

Comment: Thank you @HaejoonLee ! I really appreciate it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems `explode` is not implemented yet. You can see all implemented methods at koalas [api reference](https://koalas.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/frame.html).

Comment: Ah, I see. Thank you...I will try to use spark's vector slicer then as I can not use Spark's explode equivalent function on my data-frame either.